# Meteor reading csv file Papa Parse

Tags: javascript, csv, meteor

guys I am new to Meteor. For my present application I am using openlayer so for openlayer I call `Template.map.onRendered` event which will load a map which has a overlay which shows marker on map and when we click on this marker an event is generated and a popup is called. Now the data to be shown in popup is hardcoded at present but I want to read it from a .csv file stored on server.

I checked online coders suggested to use Papa Parse with this code.

```
Papa.parse("http://example.com/file.csv", {
    download: true,
    complete: function(results) {
        console.log(results);
    }
});
```

My problems are:

1. But, I don't understand the code and how to use it to solve my
   problem.
2. And also doing like this is safe or not in terms of browser
   compatibility?
3. And in which folder I should save this .csv file. On internet it says private folder.

Sorry, I can't share the code using Jsfiddle as it is a private code and I am not allowed to share it.

Comment: Will the .csv file be sent to client-side or will it be only on server-side?

Comment: @Nivedit .csv file will be at server-side and I just want to load that data into a array.

Answer (score 2):

PapaParse is mainly for client-side usage. It also has a Meteor wrapper, [harrison:papa-parse](https://atmospherejs.com/harrison/papa-parse), so you can try installing that as well:

`meteor add harrison:papa-parse`

**Parse file via URL:**

To parse CSV file on the server side via URL, you can try using the [Parse Remote File](http://papaparse.com/docs#remote-files) option:

```
Papa.parse(url, {
    download: true,
    // rest of config ...
})
```

**Parse file via CSV String:**

Else you can store the file in [`/private`](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#special-directories) folder, as it is a good option in Meteor to keep the file secure.

You can then access the file `/private/file.csv` using [`Assets.getText()`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/assets.html#Assets-getText) method that will return a UTF-8 encoded string.

You can include the [PapaParse string function](http://papaparse.com/docs#strings) in the `Assets.getText()` callback. After that, you can wrap the resulting function in a [Meteor method](https://guide.meteor.com/methods.html), which you can call from the client using `Meteor.call()`:

```
Meteor.methods({
    'parseFile'() {
        // read private asset as text
        Assets.getText('/private/file.csv', (error, result) => {
          if(error) {
            return console.log(error);
          }
          // 'result' should be a UTF-8 string, 
          // parse it using PapaParse string function
          return Papa.parse(result)
        });
    }
});
```

See if that works, read the documentation for more details.

If it doesn't work, check to see if you can read the source file at all on server-side. Often, it turns out to be a relative path error.

**Alternative: BabyParse**

You can also try to use the PapaParse Node.js fork called [BabyParse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babyparse), available on NPM. However, it cannot read files, only strings. So you will first have to read the CSV file via `Assets.getText()` and convert it into a CSV string. You can then feed the CSV string into BabyParse to get your result.

Comment: wow thats seems good .. and good explanation.. i ll try that and will get back you if it works and will accept this as excepted answer..

Comment: Hi Nivedit, do we have to include  <script src="PapaParse/papaparse.js"></script> in html..

Comment: And also how will you call this method I used Meteor.call('parseFile', (err, res) => {
                if (err) {
                    alert(err);
                } else {
                    // success!
                }
            });

Comment: @ArjunChaudhary, you should install PapaParse via npm and then take a read through the Meteor docs on how to include npm packages in your code: http://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html . Your Meteor method call also looks okay to me.

Comment: { data: [ [ '/buildingData.csv' ] ],
I20160905-15:24:08.942(10)?   errors:
I20160905-15:24:08.942(10)?    [ { type: 'Delimiter',
I20160905-15:24:08.943(10)?        code: 'UndetectableDelimiter',
I20160905-15:24:08.943(10)?        message: 'Unable to auto-detect delimiting character; defaulted to
 \',\'',
I20160905-15:24:08.944(10)?        row: undefined } ],
I20160905-15:24:08.944(10)?   meta:
I20160905-15:24:08.945(10)?    { delimiter: ',',
I20160905-15:24:08.946(10)?      linebreak: '\n',

Comment: I think there is a problem with path. My file is inside server folder and .csv file inside private folder

Comment: Please update the question with your new code, project file structure and errors.

Comment: You cant access the private folder directly thats the problem . one way round is to use Assets .

Comment: Okay, you can either use Assets methods if your project is ES6, or keep the file somewhere inside your server folder in a subdirectory and take care not to serve it to the client. The new ES6 architecture makes this easier to manage. Ref: http://docs.meteor.com/api/assets.html (ES6) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21172215/meteor-private-subdirectory (ES5)